# объявление переменной без спецификации, CTAD(с++17), возможно ли это? Выводит ошибки, не могу понять как это сделать

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;


template<class T1>
class TypeSize {
public:
    TypeSize(T1 value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
    void DataTypeSize()
    {
        cout << "value" << sizeof(value) << endl;
    }
protected:
    T1 value;
};


template<class T1>
class TypeInfo: public TypeSize<T1> { 
public:
    TypeInfo(T1 value) : TypeSize<T1>::TypeSize(value) {

    }
    void ShowTypeName() {
        cout << "type name: " << typeid(this->value).name() << endl;
    }
    TypeInfo() :TypeSize<void>(){  }
};

int main()
{
    
    double a = 2;
    TypeInfo<double> c(a);
    TypeInfo type;
    TypeSize size;
    c.DataTypeSize();
    c.ShowTypeName();

 
}
```

Comment: я хочу создать объект базового или производного класса без указания спецификации, с конструктором по умолчанию     TypeInfo type;    TypeSize size; ,

Comment: Как вы думаете: как компилятор должен вычислить тип, когда его не указали? Ответ: никак - информации недостаточно.

Comment: @MaximTimakov а если добавить спецификацию на тип void , должна же быть какая то извращенная фича , или я страдаю аутизмом хм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблонный параметр для класса выводится из типа аргументов конструктора. Нет аргументов — нет типов...
Сами подумайте, на основании чего компилятор может вывести тип в этой строке:

```
TypeInfo type;
```

Вы сами хоть можете сказать, вам нужен `TypeInfo<int> type;` или `TypeInfo,double> type;`?

И еще — когда вы говорите о `void`, то учтите, что ни присваивание `void`, ни получение его размера через `sizeof` невозможно...

И если вторую проблему можно решить с помощью специализации, ну, например, как

```
template<class T1>
class TypeSize {
public:
    TypeSize(T1 value) { this->value = value; }
    void DataTypeSize() { cout << "value" << sizeof(value) << endl; }
protected:
    T1 value;
};

template<>
class TypeSize<void> {
public:
    TypeSize() {}
    void DataTypeSize() { cout << "void" << endl; }
};

template<class T1>
class TypeInfo: public TypeSize<T1> { 
public:
    TypeInfo(T1 value) : TypeSize<T1>::TypeSize(value) {}
    void ShowTypeName() { cout << "type name: " << typeid(this->value).name() << endl;}
    TypeInfo() :TypeSize<void>(){}
};

template<>
class TypeInfo<void>: public TypeSize<void> {
public:
    TypeInfo() {}
    void ShowTypeName() {cout << "type name: void" << endl; }
};
```

То первую так просто решить не удастся, шаблонный параметр придется указывать, пусть и `void`.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

P.S. И еще — уже не по сути вопроса — когда вы ставили метку "шаблоны", разве вы не видели, что в описании написано — для С++ templates использовать метку "шаблоны-с++", метка "шаблоны" предназначена для шаблонов проектирования...